# Wikidata: SPARQL Select items only if they do not include a property

Tags: sparql, wikidata

**Problem #1**

To find people I use

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q5.
}
```

but to find people still alive I would like to exclude people have not defined one among this property 570, 509, 20.
how can I do?

**Problem #2**

To find tennis tournaments I use

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q13219666.
}
```

Unfortunately, some tournaments are not identified directly and therefore use:

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q13219666.
}
```

However, I am also returned to the editions of a tournament, such as '2000 wimbledon', '2001 wimbledon', etc while I would like to get only 'wimbledon'. How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: #1: `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}`

Comment: #2 is a data quality problem. `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE
{ ?item wdt:P31?/wdt:P279? wd:Q13219666. filter not exists {?item wdt:P585 []}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} # values(?item){(wd:Q41520)}` seems to be a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As offered in comments...

#### #1 by @aksw

> ```
> FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
> ```

#### #2 by @stanislav-kralin

> This is a data quality problem. This [appears to be a workaround](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%20wdt%3AP31%3F%2Fwdt%3AP279%3F%20%20wd%3AQ13219666%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%20wdt%3AP585%20%20[]%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%23%20uncomment%20the%20following%20line%20if%20desired%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%20%28wd%3AQ41520%29%20%7D):
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel 
> WHERE { ?item  wdt:P31?/wdt:P279?  wd:Q13219666 . 
>         FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?item  wdt:P585  [] } 
>         SERVICE wikibase:label 
>           { bd:serviceParam  wikibase:language  "en" . } 
>       } 
> # uncomment the following line if desired
>       # VALUES (?item) { (wd:Q41520) }
> ```

Comment: Thank you! While I'm quite clear about the meaning of '[ ]' in # 2 What does it mean in '?o' in # 2? Also you talk about 'data quality problem', I thought the same initially, however from my little experience, I could notice this 'structure' is quite frequent at least for 'recurring events'... In this regard, I also noticed that there are many duplicate voices and nonsense alias as the name of a song as alias of the singer ... :) However I find wikidata a fantastic service!

Comment: @Amedeo - Anywhere `[]` occurs, it basically serves as an indefinite pronoun, and represents a blank (or _unnamed_) node. Frequent but inconsistent structure, duplicate voices, and nonsense aliases would all be considered "data quality problems". Further followup should probably be raised as separate Questions.